# Android - AlertDialog styling

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I have an alert dialog in the app as shown below.

[image]

I want the title and the line which separates the title - message body to be in orange colour. how can i do this?
What i tried is using custom style as shown below. But this did not work.

```
<style name="AboutDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="android:textColor">#E5492A</item>
</style>
```

my alert dialog code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.context, R.style.AboutDialog));
alertDialog.setTitle("Sample");
        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.rate_dialog_text);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.rate_now_text,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        MainActivity.context.startActivity(new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                        .parse("market://details?id="
                                                + MainActivity.APP_PNAME)));
                        if (editor != null) {
                            editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.remind_later_text,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no_thanks_text,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (editor != null) {
                            editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        return alertDialog.create();

    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.context, R.style.AboutDialog));
```

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AboutDialog);
```

NOTE: This is only available for API 11 (Android 3.0) and above.

If you need to to support Android < 3.0 you probably have to create a custom dialog (instead of using `AlertDialog`

**EDIT Added really sleazy reflection-based hack**

If you are really stuck and don't want to implement a custom dialog, then try the following.

After you've built the dialog and just before you want to return it, instead of this:

```
return alertDialog.create();
```

do this:

```
AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.create(); // Create the dialog
// Add listener so we can modify the dialog before it is shown
ad.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        // Set the text color on the dialog title and separator
        setTextColor(dialogInterface, 0xFFE5492A);
    }
});
return ad;
```

Now add this very nasty reflection-based method:

```
public void setTextColor(DialogInterface alert, int color) {
    try {
        Class c = alert.getClass();
        Field mAlert = c.getDeclaredField("mAlert");
        mAlert.setAccessible(true);
        Object alertController = mAlert.get(alert);
        c = alertController.getClass();
        Field mTitleView = c.getDeclaredField("mTitleView");
        mTitleView.setAccessible(true);
        Object dialogTitle = mTitleView.get(alertController);
        TextView dialogTitleView = (TextView)dialogTitle;
        // Set text color on the title
        dialogTitleView.setTextColor(color);
        // To find the horizontal divider, first
        //  get container around the Title
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)dialogTitleView.getParent();
        // Then get the container around that container
        parent = (ViewGroup)parent.getParent();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                // We got an ImageView, that should be the separator
                ImageView im = (ImageView)v;
                // Set a color filter on the image
                im.setColorFilter(color);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore any exceptions, either it works or it doesn't
    }
}
```

I tested this on Android 2.2 and Android 4.0 and it works. It may not do exactly what you want, so you'll need to try it. I can't guarantee it will work on all devices or on future versions of Android, since it depends a lot on the way the `AlertDialog` class is implemented (if they change that in the future this probably won't work anymore).

Just a few notes for anyone who cares:

1. The reason that I use `setOnShowListener()` is because you can't actually get to the internal `View` objects that `AlertDialog` uses until after they have been inflated. They don't get inflated immediately when you create an `AlertDialog`, it happens some time later. Using the listener we can get control after the layout is inflated but before the `Dialog` is shown.
2. I'm using reflection to access in internal member variables in the `AlertDialog` implementation. Once I get access to the `TextView` that contains the title, I have to monkey around to find the horizontal line that is used to separate the title from the message. To do this I get the `Layout` that surrounds the title (this `Layout` contains the alert icon and title text). Then I get the `Layout` that surrounds that (this `Layout` wraps the icon, title text and the separator). Then I look at all children of the surrounding layout and set the color on all `ImageView` objects in there. The separator is implemented as an `ImageView` using a drawable, therefore it isn't possible to just change the color. Note: An alternative to using `setColorFilter()` would be to replace the drawable in the ImageView with a suitably colored drawable here.

Thanks for the challenge, it was kinda fun to figure this out :-D

Comment: am still unable to make it work. this is what i get if done as u sugested. http://i.imgur.com/aEUuCbE.png

Comment: Added another solution based on reflection. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the brilliant hack. It should work. But after using this logic what i am getting is like shown here http://i.imgur.com/zCjvsrf.png

Comment: Have you set a theme on your application or your activity in the manifest? What version of Android OS are you using? Is this on an emulator or a device? If device, what device?

Comment: Ya. I have set my custom theme in manifest to style action bar. I guess this is giving some problem. I am using JB. its on device. Nexus 7

Comment: You can try going back to `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.context, R.style.AboutDialog));` and see if that changes anything. For some reason you are using another theme.

Comment: OK. Please let me know the results.

Answer (score 2):

by the way its a late answer, maybe it will be useful for someone. to create Custom AlertDialog and have the same neat buttons like the Default AlertDialog. follow the simple method below

```
final AlertDialog.Builder demoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final LayoutInflater inflator = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.passcode_req_dialog_template, null);

        demoDialog.setView(view)

            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

        final AlertDialog dialog = passwordDialog.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Get the work done here when pressing positive button
                dialog.dismiss(); 
            }
        });

        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Get the work done here when pressing negative button
                dialog.dismiss();   
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a `custom layout` for dialog and provide that `layout` to your alert dialog by using

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customDialogLayout);
```

You can see this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) for custom dialog.

Comment: I dont wanted to use custom dialog. because the buttons in custom dialog looks something like this http://i.imgur.com/aEUuCbE.png . but i want something like shown in the question which is smooth and neat. can i achieve this using custom dialog?

Comment: of course, you can. You can design your layout from any `graphics` developer, who tell you all necessary color code, text size, text color and borders etc.

Comment: can u please show me some tutorial or sample code to get the buttons in custom layout as shown in the question?

Comment: You can create a `TableLayout` having **3** columns. Each have a `TextView` with `gray` background.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use this project [AlertDialogPro](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro).
Include this project to yours and define your theme like below:

```
<style name="YourAppTheme.AlertDialogProTheme" parent="AlertDialogProTheme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Custom the title -->
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/YourDialogWindowTitle</item>
    <!-- Change the title line to orange -->
    <item name="adpTitleDividerBackground">#E5492A</item>
</style>

<style name="YourDialogWindowTitle" parent="DialogWindowTitle.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#E5492A</item>
</style>
```

And specify this theme to your app's theme with attribute "alertDialogProTheme":

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  ...
  <item name="alertDialogProTheme">@style/YourAppTheme.AlertDialogProTheme</item>
</style>
```

Use AlertDialogPro.Builder to build dialog:

```
AlertDialogPro.Builder builder = new AlertDialogPro.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name).
    setMessage("Message").
    setPositiveButton("Rate Now", null).
    setNeutralButton("Remind me later", null).
    setNegativeButton("No,thanks", null).
    show();
```

[image: screenshot]