# AlertDialog theme not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

my source

```
private static final int ALERT_DIALOG = 1;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // buildAlertMessageExit();

        showDialog(ALERT_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        if (id == ALERT_DIALOG) {
            ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
                    R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
            builder.setMessage("Hello World")
                    .setTitle("Alert Dialog")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Close",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
            dialog = builder.create();
        }
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = super.onCreateDialog(id);
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> 
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
   </style>
```

**and as a result there is no theme**

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to have a transparent background? Then try `@color/transparent`.

Comment: @Dhaval Sodha Parmar - I want to make the dialogue with the theme

Answer (score 5):

insted of this:

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
                    R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
```

try

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,
                R.style.AlertDialogCustom_);
```

**`But its require MIN API LEVEL 11.`**

If you need to to support `Android >= 3.0` you probably have to create a `custom dialog` (instead of using `AlertDialog`.

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770728/1168654) for more detail.

Comment: <3.0 ?? Are you sure? FYI, [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) is available since API level 1

Comment: @PareshMayani : read Proper : But its require MIN API LEVEL 11 not API 1.