# Change background color of items in AlertDialog set with setSingleChoiceItems/setItems

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

in the last days I read lots of questions, answers and solutions regarding customization of AlertDialogs in Android. Still, none of them helped me out completely.

So my question is:
**What Layout-element is used when adding Items via `setSingleChoiceItems` or `setItems` to an `AlertDialog`?**

**Note:** I want to style it in code, not via theme/style-solutions!

To this point I used a combination of the following answers to achieve a customized title, title-content-divider and different button colors.
[Android - AlertDialog styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770400/android-alertdialog-styling/14770728#14770728)
[Changing the background drawable of the searchview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget/11669808#11669808)

My customized Dialog looks like this:
[image]

As you can see I achieved to dye the background of the title and the buttons in white as well as coloring the title itself and the divider in red but not the color of those single-choice items.
For that, I took a look into the android-sources, specifically "[alert_dialog_holo.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog_holo.xml)". I found the `AlertDialog` is built of multiple `LinearLayouts` nested into each other (I took this approach from the second Link). After determining the elements I wanted to style I used the approach of Link 1 (defining an `onShowListener` to the `AlertDialog`) to change their color. This worked pretty well for every element, whether it was the title, the divider, the buttons or even the content (standard text-content as well as custom content such as a `DatePicker`).
Now I'm stuck on the last part (see question above) as it seems that those items are not being loaded into the `ScrollView` of a "normal" content, neither in the `FrameLayout` of a custom content (which I managed to style with white background).
So can someone please point me to the layout-elements that are used when the methods `setSingleChoiceItems` or `setItems` are used?

For completion I add the code how I created the shown AlertDialog, and how I styled it:

**Creation of the Dialog:**

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle(getString(R.string.currency_choose))
.setCancelable(false)
.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.currencies, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        currency = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currencies)[which].substring(0, 1);
    }
})
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // doSomething with clicked item
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogOnShowListener()); // here happens the styling
dialog.show();
```

**Styling of the Dialog (excerpt, but should be enough to get the idea):**

```
@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Dialog d = ((Dialog) dialog);

    int divierId = d.getContext().getResources()
        .getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    View divider = d.findViewById(divierId);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(red); // earlier defined color-int
}
```

Thanks in advance, chuky

Comment: How did you change the bar title from blue to red? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I found the solution, so if everyone else should ever come across this problem here's how I've done it:

It feels like a really crappy solution, but I just searched for the ID of a List-Element the moment it was clicked and apparently every List-Element can be styled with this ID.
The Code I used to get the ID was the following:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle(getString(R.string.currency_choose))
.setCancelable(false)
.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.currencies, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // -------------- here I got the ID ----------- //
        System.out.println(((Dialog)dialog).getCurrentFocus().toString());
        // doSomething with clicked item
    }
})
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        DBs.getDBSettings().writeSetting("CURRENCY", currency);
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogOnShowListener());
dialog.show();
```

The ID that was part of this `View`s `toString`-method is "**android:id/select_dialog_listview**".

Finally a screenshot showing my solution:
[image]

Greetings, chuky

Comment: can you please tell me how did you change the title color and the divider color? Thanks

Comment: It's actually written in the question. Read it again and give the last code block special attention. There you can see the code that I used to style the divider. The title can be styled exactly alike, you just need another ID...